# What is the source for the icon/tile for a find result in Windows 10 for a UWP app?

Tags: uwp, windows-10

What is the source of the tile/icon that is displayed for Search results in Windows 10? It doesn't seem to correspond with anything in the visual assets section of my manifest. I have gone through all the images in the assets folder and none of them are the same as what is being displayed.

I have been updating the tiles and icons for my app and most of them look the way I want, except for the case described above. I have tried clearing the tile cache, which did not affect it.

The app is installed from running it in debug mode from Visual Studio. I have tried uninstalling it and then performing a clean and rebuild.

I updated the app in the app store and installed it after removing the debug version. It shows the wrong tile as well.

Here is a screenshot of the context I am referring to, using Spotify to illustrate:

[image: Sample search results showing the tile]

Answer (score 0):

> What is the source for the icon/tile for a find result in Windows 10 for a UWP app?

The search results come from your app's file indexing, System will rebuild the indexing at intervals, but it can't make sure the search result is updated. For this problem, you could try restart your os, you rebuild indexing manually.

**open control pane-> indexing option-> Advanced button-> rebuild**

And you could also try to uninstall the app, and reinstall it.

Comment: None of these worked. I've also tried disk cleanup including clean system files.

Comment: Yes, multiple times. I tried all your suggestions.

Comment: what about other app?

Comment: the problem only occurs from your app?

Comment: Yes the issue is with the app I am developing on the machine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234054/discussion-between-cocaicedew-and-neutralhandle).

Comment: have your tried clean your solution and rebuild the app.

Comment: Yes, I updated the question to mention that earlier.

Comment: it only occurs in current machine? have tested with other machine?

Comment: Not tested elsewhere yet. I'll check the next release to app store on another machine if it is not fixed locally first. That will be within a couple of days.

Comment: Ok, I met similar problem after OS update.